# Mesos Json to Kubernetes YAML

Tags: docker, kubernetes, yaml, mesos, marathon

I'm moving an Apache Mesos application, where my configurations are based in JSON, to Kubernetes, where my configurations are based in YAML. Would the JSON configuration files work as a YAML file since YAML is a superset of JSON, or would I need to write a new YAML file?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, JSON works as well, it's just more pain than YAML to write it, manually. Also, you may be able to use [micahhausler/container-transform](https://github.com/micahhausler/container-transform) to convert your Marathon specs to Kubernetes specs.

Comment: Would JSON work natively or would I have to use the typical yaml style? Also, I've got multiple JSON files but, for my deployment, I need to have only one yaml file. Is it possible to combine the JSON files into one yaml file?

Comment: It works natively but unlike in YAML you can't combine multiple JSON files, no.

Comment: What do you mean by "unlike in YAML". So I can combine YAML files but not JSON files. So I can't move the JSON files to YAML and then combine them?

Comment: Sorry, I should have been more clear: you can't combine multiple JSONs using `---` but you'd need to use a list resource as shown in https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/master/hack/testdata/multi-resource-list.json … hope that makes sense?

Comment: If I transform them into yaml files using the container-transform, could I then combine multiple yaml files into one?

Comment: Yes, just separate them with `---`

Comment: So for container-transform, would the proper command be `container-transform -i marathon -o kubernetes _____` where ______ represents the file name?